# Troubleshooting Access Denied on SAMBA

Tags: permissions, samba, samba4

I'm new to SAMBA, but have set  up a SAMBA server on an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop, but consistently get Access Denied, when trying to map any SAMBA share from my Windows 11 laptop. How do I troubleshoot the problem?
Here's what I believe to be the relevant parts of smb.conf:

```
[global]
server role = standalone server
obey pam restrictions = yes
security = user
encrypt passwords = true
map to guest = bad user
guest account = nobody

[media]
path=/data/media
valid users = @media
  guest ok = no
  writable = yes
  browsable = yes
[public]
path=/data/public
valid users = @smbgroup
  guest ok = no
  writable = yes
  browsable = yes

[documents]
path=/data/documents
valid users = @simon
  guest ok = no
  writable = yes
  browsable = yes
[downloads]
path=/data/downloads
valid users = @media
  guest ok = no
  writable = yes
  browsable = yes
```

Here are the permissions on the relevant shared folders:

```
root@KTchia01:/data# ls -l
total 100375
drwxrwx---  8 simon simon           27 Jun  8  2021 documents
drwxrwx---  2 simon simon            6 Jun  8  2021 downloads
drwxrwxr-x 16 simon media           17 Jun 10  2021 media
-rw-r--r--  1 chia  chia     102672297 Jun  8  2021 oldhome.tgz
drwxrwxrwx  2 simon smbgroup         2 Feb  5 21:20 public
```

I connect as the user simon from the Windows 11 laptop KTLAPTOP02, and simon is both an ordinary user on the linux box and has set a SMB password. Group memberships for simon:

```
root@KTchia01:~# grep simon /etc/group
adm:x:4:syslog,simon,chia
cdrom:x:24:simon
sudo:x:27:simon,chia
dip:x:30:simon
plugdev:x:46:simon
lpadmin:x:120:simon
lxd:x:131:simon
simon:x:1000:
sambashare:x:132:simon
smbgroup:x:1001:simon
plex:x:998:simon,plex
media:x:1002:simon,plex
chia:x:1003:simon
```

Log output, when trying to connect:

```
root@KTchia01:/var/log/samba# tail -f log.ktlaptop02
[2022/02/05 21:41:36.200402,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2864(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[public]"
[2022/02/05 21:41:36.200454,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2864(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[documents]"
[2022/02/05 21:41:36.200509,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2864(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[downloads]"
[2022/02/05 21:41:36.212158,  1] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:362(create_connection_session_info)
  create_connection_session_info: user 'simon' (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (IPC$)
[2022/02/05 21:41:36.212187,  1] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:543(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to further troubleshoot, why I get Access Denied, regardless of which share I try to access?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some good troubleshooting steps, shamelessly copied from [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/744315):

1. Maybe your Windows host is prepending your username with the wrong domain name. From the Windows machine, try to login using `localhost\simon` as the username
2. Issue `sudo pdbedit -L` (must run as root) and check if user `simon` is listed. If so, set a trivial password (you can change it later) using `smbpasswd simon`
3. If user `simon` is not listed, try to recreate it issuing `smbpasswd -a simon`
4. If it does not work, delete the passwd file (it is named `passwd.tdb`; for reference, it is found under `/var/lib/samba/private/`). Then, recreate your user issuing `smbpasswd -a simon`
5. If it still not working, try to use the root account issuing `smbpasswd -a root` and check if you can login using the root user. Note: this is only a try. After having done with it, you must delete root's entry issuing `smbpasswd -x root`
6. Your last resort is to increase the verbosity of logging and see if you can find clues there. For authentication attempts, edit or add the following line on your `smb.conf`: `log level = 2 winbind:5`, check the logs with something like `tail -f /var/log/samba/log*` and try to login.

Hope some of it helps.

Comment: That apparently got me some more detailed info. I can see from the samba logs, that I connect as the correct user ( simon or root), but it also states, that said user 
not permitted to access this share (IPC$)

Comment: Did you try resetting the Samba password database? Unfortunately, I can't see anything wrong with your config. 

Comment: Yes. According to the log file available in full at http://home.kepp.tech/samba/log.ktlaptop02
Authentication appears to succeed, but authorization seems to fail.

Comment: All relevant configuration and log files now available at http://http://home.kepp.tech/samba/

Comment: Already found a solution? I have nearly the same problem... even a share in /samba with 0777 isnt accessible through any network device

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and finale found a solution as mentioned [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/root-tip-how-to-basic-samba-setup-and-troubleshooting/100420).

AppArmor and Samba may interfere each other after updates or not being properly configured. The suggested solution is to activate complaint-mode for AppArmor's smbd:

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.smbd
```

However you could also add Site-specific additions in `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.smbd` to get access.

Comment: This was it, thank you! Only solution on the Internet that worked for me on the Manjaro.